# Open the category when clicking

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How to make to open the category when clicking and closed back.

[image]

I found one tutorial (http://plnkr.co/edit/ReNCjeCN8qwxI58RaMRd?p=preview), but when clicked it displays only the first link. How to make each item appear exactly as in the menu?

**Code :**

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="windows-1251">
    <title>Выпадающий текст при нажатии на ссылку с помощью jQuery</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(".link").click(function() {
            $("this").find(".nested_menu").slideToggle("slow");
            $(this).toggleClass("active"); return false;
        });
    </script>
    <style>
        .nasted_menu {    
            display: none;
            padding: 5px;
            width: 400px;
            height: 200px;
            background: #09F;
            color: #FFF;
            }
        .link {
            background: #CCC;
            color: #06F;
            }
        .active {
            background: #FF9;
            }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
  <ul>
  <li class="link">Link1
    <ul class="nested_menu">
      <li>Nested point</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="link">Link2
  ...
  </li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: could you share your code? =)

Comment: @RudolfManusadzhyan 
with what code?

Comment: Your code with menu.. where more than 1 link =) and then we may be understand what's wrong =)

Comment: @RudolfManusadzhyan For example [look please this link](http://plnkr.co/edit/ReNCjeCN8qwxI58RaMRd?p=preview) 
and Click now `Click me 2` `Click me 3` on these links, they all only display the first panel, description click me 2-3 no shows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(function() {
  $(".btn-slide").click(function() {
    $(this).next("#panel").slideToggle("slow");//use $(this) to get the clicked btnslide
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
    return false;
  });
});
```

```css
#panel {
  display: none;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #09F;
  color: #FFF;
}
.btn-slide {
  background: #CCC;
  color: #06F;
}
.active {
  background: #FF9;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="" class="btn-slide">Click Me</a>
<div id="panel">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex
  ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue
  duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.
</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<a href="" class="btn-slide">Click Me 2</a>
<div id="panel">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam
</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<a href="" class="btn-slide">Click Me 3</a>
<div id="panel">
  at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.
</div>
```

1. Use `$(this)` to get the clicked `btnslide`
2. Use `.next()` to get the content of the clicked `btnslide`

Comment: @TriSTaR glad to help mate

Comment: [The `id` attribute must be unique.](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute)

Answer (score 0):

UPD. fixed `$("this")` => `$(this)`.

```js
$(".link").click(function() {
  $(this).find(".nested_menu").slideToggle("slow");
  $(this).toggleClass("active"); return false;
});
```

```css
.nested_menu {    
  display: none;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #09F;
  color: #FFF;
}
.link {
  background: #CCC;
  color: #06F;
}
.active {
  background: #FF9;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="link">Link1
    <ul class="nested_menu">
      <li>Nested point</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="link">Link2
  ...
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thus? http://plnkr.co/edit/ReNCjeCN8qwxI58RaMRd?p=preview I am sorry if I did not understand :(

Comment: yeah, man. My bad. instead of `$("this")` I should have used `$(this)` (without quotes) =)